# Google Apps Script - Require One Response Per Row for Grid Item

Tags: google-apps-script

I am creating some student surveys with Google Forms using Google Apps Script. The question type I'm using is a grid item. Each row is a question about the teacher and each column is a rating (strongly disagree, disagree, etc...).

When creating a form using the normal Forms interface there is an option to require a response for each row within a grid item. I've searched through all the documentation and it appears there is no way to set this using GAS. Am I missing something or is there any workaround?

I can go in and manually set this after all forms have been created but there are a lot of classes and teachers so it will be quite time-consuming.

Here is the code so far:

```js
function createForm() {
  var form = FormApp.create('Student Survey');  
  
  var questions = getQuestions();
  var ratings = getRatings();
  
  var grid = form.addGridItem();
  
  grid.setTitle("Please answer the following questions about your teacher.");
  grid.setRows(questions);
  grid.setColumns(ratings);
  grid.isRequired();
  
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little sneaky, but it is there!

**For one response per *row*:** Use your [GridItem's](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/grid-item#setrequiredenabled)
`.setRequired(true);`

**For one response per *column*:** Check out the [GridItem's setValidation()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/grid-item#setValidation(GridValidation)) method. It takes a [GridValidation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/grid-validation) parameter you can build with the [GridValidationBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/grid-validation-builder).
See the second section of code below.

---

Here is your code with **both** validation types:

```
function createForm() {
  var form = FormApp.create('Student Survey');  

  var questions = getQuestions();
  var ratings = getRatings();

  var grid = form.addGridItem();

  grid.setTitle("Please answer the following questions about your teacher.");
  grid.setRows(questions);
  grid.setColumns(ratings);

  grid.setRequired(true); //This part is to require one response per row


  //This section requires one response per column.
  var gridValidation = FormApp.createGridValidation()
    .setHelpText("HELP TEXT")
    .requireLimitOneResponsePerColumn()
    .build();

  grid.setValidation(gridValidation);

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that only requires one response per column. I need to require one response in each row. In the Form editor there is a switch to toggle that option on and off but can't find it anywhere in GAS.

Comment: @jjmichael I completely missed that piece of your question. I've updated my answer. It should now work for rows (see comments in code). I've left both type use for future users.